# Wordpress Navigation Menu Hover States & Drop Downs Working, But Menu Not Clickable

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, nav

The navigation menu for the Wordpress site that I am working on seems to display properly and when mouse is hovered over individual menu items, hover states do appear as well as the drop down menus (where applicable). The issue that I am having is that none of the navigation menu items are clickable (even the drop downs). It's a simple one-fourth/three-fourth header setup. Nothing fancy. All other links throughout the body of the site are clickable.

Looking at the code I did not see any DIV laying on top of the menu (hovers and drop downs wouldn't fire if there was). I went thru the CSS and nothing jumped out at me. I tried changing nearby DIVs to display:none to see if I could find a culprit...nothing. There are only two plugins running All-In-One-SEO & Formidable Forms.

The site can be found at http://www.bigfootpw.com.php56-1.dfw3-1.websitetestlink.com/

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem with your JavaScript. Mostly the problem will be on http://www.bigfootpw.com.php56-1.dfw3-1.websitetestlink.com/wp-content/themes/striking_r/js/custom.combine.js. Try turing off the JavaScript in your browser it will works.

I can't able to dig deeply on to this script.

Comment: With your help I found the conflict! A class I was using in the stylesheet was also triggering class for a completely different function in that same javascript file you pointed to. All fixed. Thank you so much!

Comment: Nice to hear, Awesome :)